# PHP MySQL query multiple products in multiple categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to output like this from the database:

```
Store name 1
--------------------
Product 1
Product 2

Store name 2
---------------------
Product 3
Product 4
```

and the query i use right now looks like this:

```
$query_stores = DB::query("SELECT * FROM `stores` LIMIT 16");

foreach($query_stores as $row){

   echo $row['name'] . '<br>';

   $query_products = DB::query("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `products` WHERE `vendor` = %i ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10" , $row['id']);

   foreach($query_products as $row2){
      echo $row2['name'] . '<br>';
   }
}
```

The code works (sort of) but i can't filter the `stores` that don't have any items in the `products` table.

Example output:

```
Store name 1

Store name 2
    --------------------
    Product 1
    Product 2

Store name 3

Store name 4
    ---------------------
    Product 3
    Product 4

Store name 5
```

Is there a better way to run the code? Can the two queries be combined?

How to exclude the `stores` from output that don't have any items in the `products` table?

Comment: Yes. See JOINs.And note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is a fairly meaningless concept.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using a single query with a join statement and build an array of data to parse and display:

```
$sql = "SELECT s.id as store_id, s.name as store_name, p.id as product_id, p.name as product_name
            FROM stores s 
            LEFT JOIN products p ON (s.id = p.vendor)
            WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY s.name ASC, p.name ASC
            LIMIT 16";
$data = DB::query($sql);
```

After the query is run, `$data` will only contain stores that have products. The `LEFT JOIN` will make sure stores are the base information and if they have no products the product columns will be `NULL`. The `WHERE` clause makes sure that you filter out any stores with no products.

Setting up a structured array will make it easier to loop through your data.

```
$stores = []; // or if PHP version < 5.4 array();
foreach($data as $row) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row['store_id'], $stores)) {
        $stores[$row['store_id']] = [
            'store_name' => $row['store_name'],
            'products' => [],
        ];
    }

    $stores[$row['store_id']]['products'][$row['product_id']] = $row['product_name'];
}
```

And for outputting:

```
foreach ($stores as $store_id => $store) {
    echo $store['name'] .'<br/>';
    foreach ($store['products'] as $product_id => $product_name) {
        echo $product_name .'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me this error: 

`QUERY: SELECT s.id as store_id, s.name as store_name, p.id as product_id, p.name as product_name FROM stores s LEFT JOIN products ON (s.id = p.vendor) WHERE p.id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY s.name ASC, p.name ASC LIMIT 16
ERROR: Unknown column 'p.id' in 'field list'`

Comment: Oops, forgot to alias the `products` table. Fixed my code.

Comment: The LIMIT appears to be wrong in this context. The OP seemed to want an indefinite number of products from a limit of 16 stores. Also, `LEFT JOIN p WHERE p.anything (except IS NULL)` is just `INNER JOIN p`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to reorder your queries so you can check if store is empty and then print if is not and if is empty then dont print it.

```
$query_stores = DB::query("SELECT * FROM `stores` LIMIT 16");

foreach($query_stores as $row){
    // put $query_products in front of echoing  and check if store is empty

    $query_products = DB::query("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `products` WHERE `vendor` = %i ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10" , $row['id']);
    // Here you check if result is empty
    if(mysql_num_rows($query_products) > 0){
        echo $row['name'] . '<br>';   

        foreach($query_products as $row2){
            echo $row2['name'] . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A good rule of thumb is 'never execute a query inside a loop'

Answer (score -1):

You could use mysql_num_rows(); function and check if number of result is < 0

Comment: this is an irrelevant answer .